# Vertically center div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, center

I have a vertical menu that pops out from the left side of the screen when clicked on. The nav inside it is vertically centered by giving it a top of 50% and transforming translateY by -50%. This works great when you open a menu item and it expands to show the children of that item. Everything stays centered like it should. The issue I am having is that I cannot scroll all the way to the top of the nav if the window is not tall enough. For some reason, if I take the transform off, I can scroll just fine. So my idea is to figure out what the top should be with jQuery/JS and change it each time a nav item is clicked. But I'm not quite sure what translateY(-50%) actually does to know what to do in jQuery.

Here is an example of my HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav__accordion">
        <li class="nav__item">
            <div class="nav__toggle">
                <div class="menu-home-container">
                    <ul id="menu-home" class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <div class="nav__toggle">About</div>
            <div class="nav__content">
                <ul class="nav__subNav">
                    <div class="menu-about-section-container">
                        <ul id="menu-about-section" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">By the Numbers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stillwater Complex</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Markets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Altar Porphyry</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Marathon-Caldwell Complex</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <div class="nav__toggle">Operations</div>
            <div class="nav__content">
                <ul class="nav__subNav">
                    <div class="menu-operations-section-container">
                        <ul id="menu-operations-section" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mining</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Processing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Recycling</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mining Methods</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <div class="nav__toggle">Responsibility</div>
            <div class="nav__content">
                <ul class="nav__subNav">
                    <div class="menu-responsibility-section-container">
                        <ul id="menu-responsibility-section" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Health &#038; Safety</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Environmental Stewardship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Economic Sustainability</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <div class="nav__toggle">People</div>
            <div class="nav__content">
                <ul class="nav__subNav">
                    <div class="menu-people-section-container">
                        <ul id="menu-people-section" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <div class="nav__toggle">Governance</div>
            <div class="nav__content">
                <ul class="nav__subNav">
                    <div class="menu-governance-section-container">
                        <ul id="menu-governance-section" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Committee Composition</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Governance Principals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Code of Conduct</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">By-Laws</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Communication with Directors</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
            <div class="nav__toggle">Investors</div>
            <div class="nav__content">
                <ul class="nav__subNav">
                    <div class="menu-investors-section-container">
                        <ul id="menu-investors-section" class="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stock Information</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Annual Reports</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Quarterly Earnings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News Releases</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Presentations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">SEC Filings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Analysts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Estimates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Annual Meeting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Online Investor Kit</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Email Alerts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Information Requests</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, /*sub, sup,*/ tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
.box-size {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica',  sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    background-color: @white;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    &.active {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

.navBar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10000;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)
}

.navBar__closeButton {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s 0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s 0s ease
}

.navBar__closeButton.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s .3s ease;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 2
}

.navBar__burgerButton {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: open .3s .1s ease-in forwards;
  -moz-animation: open .3s .1s ease-in forwards;
  -ms-animation: open .3s .1s ease-in forwards
}

.navBar__burgerButton.active {
  stroke-dasharray: 100%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: close .3s 0s ease-in forwards;
  -moz-animation: close .3s 0s ease-in forwards;
  -ms-animation: close .3s 0s ease-in forwards
}

@-moz-keyframes close {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100%
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes close {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes close {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes open {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100%
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes open {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100%
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}

@keyframes open {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100%
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
  }
}

.nav {
  background: url('../../uploads/2015/12/global/navGradient.png');
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 9500;
  left: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: none
}

.nav.transWidth {
  -webkit-transition: width .3s .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .3s .1s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .3s .1s ease;
  -o-transition: width .3s .1s ease
}

.nav.active {
  width: 300px
}

.nav__accordion {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s .1s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.nav__accordion.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s .1s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s ease
}

.nav__accordion a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}

.nav__toggle {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s 0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s 0s ease
}

.nav__toggle:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #c9a74c;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  left: -300px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s 0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s 0s ease
}

.nav__toggle--mobile:before {
  background-color: transparent
}

.nav__toggle:hover,
.nav__toggle:hover a {
  color: #000
}

.nav__toggle:hover,
.nav__toggle--mobile:hover a {
  color: #fff
}

.nav__toggle:hover:before {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s 0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s 0s ease
}

.nav__item {
  height: 15%;
  display: block
}

.nav__subNav li {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s 0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s 0s ease
}

.nav__subNav li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(201, 167, 76, 0.35)
}

.nav__subNav li.mobile:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)
}

.nav__subNav li.hover {
  background-color: rgba(201, 167, 76, 0.35) !important
}

.hover {
  background-color: #c9a74c;
  font-weight: 900
}
```

My JS:

```
var navigation = {
  openNav: function() {
    $('.navBar__burgerButton').click(function() {
      $('.nav, .pageDim, .pageWrap, .nav__accordion, .closeAll, body').addClass('active');
      $(this).attr('class', 'navBar__burgerButton active');
      $('.navBar__closeButton').attr('class', 'navBar__closeButton active');

      if ($('.nav').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.pageWrap').addClass('slidePageRight');
      }

      if (windowWidth <= 1080) {
        $('body').css({
          'overflow': 'hidden'
        })
      }
    });
  },

  closeNav: function() {
    $('.navBar__closeButton').click(function() {
      closeNav();
    });
    var closeNav = function() {
      $('.nav, .pageDim, .pageWrap, .nav__accordion, .closeAll, body').removeClass('active');
      $('.navBar__burgerButton').attr('class', 'navBar__burgerButton');
      $('.navBar__closeButton').attr('class', 'navBar__closeButton');
      $('.navScrollBug').removeClass('active');
      // Slides back to normal
      if (!$('.nav').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.pageWrap').removeClass('slidePageRight');
      }

      if (windowWidth <= 1080) {
        $('body').css({
          'overflow': ''
        })
      }
    }
    $('.closeAll').click(function() {
      closeNav();
    });
  },

  showScrollBug: function() {
    var wH = $(window).height();
    var nI = $('.nav__item').length;
    var i = (nI * 50) + 81;

    $('.navBar__burgerButton').on('click', function() {
      if ($('.nav__toggle').hasClass('hover')) {
        var c = $('.nav__toggle.hover').next().find('.nav__subNav').height();
        var navH = i + c;
        if (navH > wH) {
          $('.navScrollBug').addClass('active');
        } else {
          $('.navScrollBug').removeClass('active');
        }
      }
    });

    $('.nav__item').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('open');

      var c = $(this).find('.nav__subNav').height();

      if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        var navH = i + c;
        $('.nav__item').not(this).removeClass('open');
        if (navH > wH) {
          $('.navScrollBug').addClass('active');
        } else {
          $('.navScrollBug').removeClass('active');
        }
      } else if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $('.navScrollBug').removeClass('active');
      }
    });
  },

  accordion: {
    dropDown: function() {
      // Hides content on nav open
      $('.nav__content').slideUp('fast');
      // Navigation Accordion
      $('.nav__accordion').find('.nav__toggle').click(function() {
        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $('.nav__content').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav__accordion > li').removeClass('hover');
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".nav__content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
      });
    },

    statusIndicator: function() {
      var pathName = window.location.pathname;
      var pathArray = pathName.split('/');
      var arrayLength = pathArray.length;
      var l = pathArray[arrayLength - 2];

      $('.nav__accordion a').each(function() {
        var n = $(this).attr('href');
        var nn = $(this).html();
        var sb = $('.sideBar a.active').html(); // Gets active state of investors sidebar nav

        var hrefArray = n.split("/");
        var hrefArrayLength = hrefArray.length;
        var nl = hrefArray[hrefArrayLength - 2];

        if (nl === l || nn === sb) {
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('hover');
          $(this).closest('.nav__content').siblings('.nav__toggle').addClass('hover');
          $(this).closest('.nav__content').siblings('.nav__toggle').closest('.nav__item').addClass('open');
          $(this).closest('.nav__content').slideDown();
        }
      });
    },

    keepHighlight: function() {
      // Holds hover state on click for Navigation Accordion
      $(".nav__toggle").click(function() {
        $(".nav__toggle").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      });
    }
  },

  interiorStickyNav: function() {
    // Interior Page NavPager Controls StickyNav
    var stickyNav = $(".stickyNav");
    var pathName = window.location.pathname;
    var pathArray = pathName.split('/');
    var arrayLength = pathArray.length;
    var href = pathArray[arrayLength - 2];

    if (href == "by-the-numbers") {
      stickyNav.addClass("sticky");
    } else {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
          stickyNav.addClass("sticky");
        } else {
          stickyNav.removeClass("sticky");
        }
      });
    }
  },
};
navigation.openNav();
navigation.closeNav();
navigation.showScrollBug();
navigation.accordion.dropDown();
navigation.accordion.statusIndicator();
navigation.accordion.keepHighlight();
navigation.interiorStickyNav();
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfud2nk4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the below jquery function to solve your issue:
give an id field to each "nav__toggle" div and use this query:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<your id name in nav__toggle>").click(function(){
        $("#menu-investors-section").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.
Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. I want to position .nav__accordion centered vertically. I am currently accomplishing this with position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); The transform is what is causing the scroll from being able to happen completely. I'd like to just change the position of top to be the right amount of space to center it vertically. I am not sure what the calculations would be to accomplish this though.